# PHP Переход на страницу при обновлении страницы

Tags: php

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Задача : Есть файл index.php. При перезагрузке страницы хочу, чтобы переходил к этому же самому файлу, таким образом обнуляя массивы $_GET и $_POST

```
$pageRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) &&
($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0' ||  
$_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] == 'no-cache'); 
if($pageRefreshed == 1){
header("Location : index.php"); 
}
```

header не работает. Постоянно выводит ошибку "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." Мне нужно либо найти способ вернуться к началу страницы или другой способ обнуления информации внутри массивов $_GET и $_POST при обновлении страницы. Заранее спасибо

---

Я просто не совсем понимаю работу функции header(), хотя читал в других постах про неё. 
Полный код :

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

if (isset($_GET[ "delete" ])) {
    $delete = $_GET[ "delete" ];
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"delete from players where PlayerID = $delete");
}

if (isset($_POST[ "nick" ])) {
$nick = $_POST[ "nick" ];
mysqli_query($link,"insert into players(PlayerName) values(\"{$nick}\")");
}

$pageRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) &&($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0' ||  $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] == 'no-cache'); 
if($pageRefreshed == 1){
    header("Location : index.php");
    echo "Page Refreshed";  
}

$result = mysqli_query($link,"select * from players");
echo "<form action = \"index.php\" method = \"get\" name = \"form\">";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "[$row[0]]Имя игрока - ".$row[1].
"<a href = \"index.php?delete={$row[0]}\">[Удалить]</a>
}
echo "</form>";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Название игры</h1>
<form action = "<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method = "post" name = "myform">

<span>Введите своё имя  </span>
<input type = "text" value = "Player" name = "nick">
<input type = "submit" name = "button">
</form>
<a href = "index.php"><button>Начать игру</button></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Вкратце, есть поле для ввода имени игрока, которое заносится в базу данных через $_POST. Выводится полная таблица и кнопка удалить, которая передает информацию через $_GET. Проблема в том, что после добавления одного игрока, переменная имени сохраняется в массиве и при каждом обновлении страницы в таблице появляется новая запись с тем же самым именем. Моим решением стало возврат к началу - к index.php. Данные в массиве проверял через print_r($_GET) и print_r($_POST)

Answer (score 1):

ошибка означает, что где-то выше в коде уже что-то выводится на страницу. Это может быть и ошибка от компилятора, и обычные `echo` и `var_dump`. Посмотрите внимательнее, а еще лучше - выкладывайте полный код, ибо чаще всего, проблема кроется не в том узком участке, в котором Вы думаете.

Массив `$_GET` вы сможете обнулить, только удалив из URI все параметры.